Emails sent using Graph from a Azure Developer Sandbox user are all rejected but Outlook emails are fine
I'm developing a solution to send emails via Microsoft Graph. I'm using an Azure Developer Sandbox subscription, and sending as one of the test user accounts which that gives you.
If I log into Outlook.com as the test user I can create and send an email message which gets delivered successfully to apparently any recipient.
When I create and send a message through Graph using the same test user credentials, and to the same recipients, they fail delivery, even if the recipient is another account on the sandbox subscription. The remote servers return:
550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP

Outlook.com offers an option to resened the messages, and when I do that and resend to the original recipient, it gets delivered.
Presumably it's not a reputation or licence issue as the emails manually sent from Outlook.com are delivered successfully. Is this by design to stop abuse of the sandbox?

Update for the benefit of anyone else with the issue.
I raised a ticket with Graph API support and they flicked a switch which allowed it to work. So it appears that it won't work by default, possibly to prevent abuse.
